# How to mask IP address of ZNC

Tags: networking, ip, proxy, irc

I have set up a znc bouncer on a VPS so the chat history and other things can be kept consistent.

That way I can also reach IRC under my VPS IP. But I want to mask that IP too.

I have heard of using domain, in which I have, but searching the IP behind a domain is really easy.

I have heard of ppl talking about using reverse proxy but I don't know if that works or not.

I don't want to use the cloaks the nets usually provide, but instead hide it from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address is always necessary in order to establish a connection. You can't really *hide* it from your end, you can only borrow someone else's by connecting through a relay. (Such as an IRC bouncer.)

Indeed that's exactly what many people use bouncers for – they "hide" their *own* IP address by having the bouncer connect to IRC on their behalf. So if you wanted to hide the bouncer's address too, you'd need to... make it connect through *another* bouncer, I guess?

More sensibly, you can make the bouncer connect through a SOCKS proxy, or a system-wide VPN. Then only the proxy's or VPN server's address will be seen by the final destination. (You'll probably need to pay for a commercial VPN service; hosting it on your own server would defeat the point.)

(Note: I'm talking about a "normal" proxy. A "reverse" proxy is something you'd use for *incoming* connections, e.g. if hosting a web server.)

The extreme option is Tor, which works like a SOCKS proxy but automatically creates 3-layer proxy connections, trying to provide high anonymity. Many IRC networks either ban Tor relays outright or require users to log in before accessing the network via Tor.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense. Since I know domain names just means one layer or redirection before your actual IP is revealed by the name server. what if I make if go through cloudflare or some other similar service? That say only cloudflare's IP would be used right?

Comment: If you're talking about Cloudflare WARP VPN – yes, that would work. But if you're talking about Cloudflare DNS/CDN service – really no. Keep in mind that connecting *out* to another service works differently than accepting inbound connections to your website. You cannot force the IRC network to "see" a domain name that points to Cloudflare; they will always see your IP address first (because that's how you establish the connection) and will derive the domain name from the IP address, not the other way around. So a completely different kind of proxying is necessary.